# Path is working through link but when i type it in the browser it fails in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My routes are like below

```
  path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'testGame',
        component:TestGame,
        children:[{path:'list',component: ListTestGame},
                  {path:'crud',component: CrudTestGame}
        ]
       },
```

When i use below list everything works fine.

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/testGame/list']"><i class="icon-game-controller"></i> baran</a>
                </li>
```

But when i type the same url in the browser it fails. Could anyone tell me why this happens ? When i use HashLocationStrategy there seems to be no problem, it only happens with PathLocationStrategy

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
simple-line-icons.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
simroll.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
inline.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
polyfills.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
scripts.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
vendor.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
font-awesome.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
simple-line-icons.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Please, explain what "it fails" means.

Comment: i have updated my question @n00dl3. Btw when i use HashLocationStrategy there seems to be no problem, it only happens with PathLocationStrategy

Comment: You need to redirect every server call to index.html.

Comment: which server are you using ?

Comment: node.js  @n00dl3

Comment: have you set all resource request in node server to return your default html page? It appears you are not handelling routes on server side, and it is trying to get the resource from server which it is not finding,

Comment: I understand the problem, thanks. @MadhuRanjan. And the hash location  strategy doesn`t go to server i suppose, because of the #.

Comment: no, it goes to the server but anything after hash are ignored for resource fetching, and your default page is served, once it is in browser angular router engine comes in picture and serves the routed path, Cheers!!